# Xcode 8.3.3 to Xcode 9.0 update

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I have recently installed Xcode 9.0, but in order to also keep the previous version (i.e. both Xcode 8.3.3 and Xcode 9.0) available on my computer, instead of using the usual App Store Updates I have followed the instructions found [here](http://iosbrain.com/blog/2017/01/02/installing-multiple-versions-of-xcode-6-7-8-side-by-side-together-on-the-same-mac/).

As much as I can see the result is pretty good.

Nevertheless the App Store application does not seem to understand that I am now up to date with Xcode 9.0.
It keeps showing me the update for it. What am I supposed to do about that? Any way to inform the App Store app?

Answer (score 2):

The instructions you linked had you keep your old version and just install the standalone version of the new.

These instructions are bad. You've just found out why.

Throw away the standalone version of the new and go ahead and let the Mac App Store update your Xcode. Then download the *old* version from https://developer.apple.com/download/more/, rename it, and stick it in /Applications.

Also don't forget that while you can keep multiple versions of Xcode 9 open at the same time, this isn't true for older versions of Xcode. If you have Xcode 8.3 running, you can't have Xcode 9 running, and vice versa.